# How do I jump back to the next-to-last insert position?

Tags: cursor-movement, mark

I can't find an easy solution to the following problem.

Consider I'm in insert mode and I need to modify something in another point of the text. I exit insert mode and then move to the point I need to edit. Now suppose I perform some commands in normal mode. When I'm done I can go back to insert mode in the last insert position with command `gi`.

The problem comes when the edit I need to do also requires another insert operation. In that case, I would lose the last insert position in mark `^` which makes the `gi` command useless.

In this case, I would need to jump to the next-to-last insert position.
Having a look  at `:marks`, such a mark is not kept. So, what's an easy way to solve this problem?

Comment: I guess I found a possible solution with `g;` and `g,`.
These navigate `:changes` list.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I can think of is to set the previous context mark `` m` `` when leaving insert mode. Then use ``` `` ``` to return to that location after editing elsewhere.

(Note: that those are backtics `` ` `` and not normal apostrophes `'`) 
A mapping like `` :inoremap  m` `` can also be useful.

(edit)
g; and g, should work great too! I'm glad I saw your comment, nicmus.